# Correct screen name typos in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working on a native mobile app that spans the iOS, Android, and WindowsPhone platforms. Google Analytics is being leveraged to track screen views and custom events (mostly based on user taps). There was a typo in the screen names that were sent to Google Analytics on one of the platforms.

As a hypothetical example, let's say there is a registration page in the app, and two of the platforms sent "Registration" as the screen name and the other platform sent "Registraton" as the screen name. The typo was corrected on the client app, but the data in Google Analytics still shows incorrect for a brief time period.

Does anyone know if it is possible to correct simple typos like this? If so, can someone point me in the right direction? Everything I've researched talks about sending data to Google Analytics rather than correcting existing data in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment to do what you're asking. I've felt this pain myself before, and in my case it usually happens with capitalization mistakes (e.g. sending both "Click" and "click").

You can use a filter to target both variations, but there's no way to go back and change data you've already sent.